# "Continue button" grayed out in "installation type" screen during 13.04 installation

Tags: system-installation, 13.04, live-usb

I'm installing Ubuntu 13.04 onto my 32-bit Intel Core 2 Duo CPU, from a live-usb. One of the screens says "Installation type", with the three options "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Vista" or "Replace Windows Vista with Ubuntu" or "Something else". No matter which of those three options I highlight, the "Continue" button is always grayed out and un-selectable. (I can only select "Quit" or "Back".) (When I highlight the second option, the word "Continue" switches to "Install Now" on the button ... but it is still grayed out and unselectable.)

Other than the fact that I cannot "continue", the installer offers no information about what's going wrong. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!! [I am also happy to hear advice about how exactly I can file a bug report about this.]

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I clicked "Back" and then "Continue" again, and now it works. Go figure...

[Update based on comments: If this doesn't work, try it again and/or wait 15 minutes.]

Comment: Not me...  It remained greyed out.

Comment: Never mind, a few more backs and eventually it enabled the button.

Comment: Have an upvote for a working answer to the most silly problem ever

Comment: This happened to me with linux mint too and this solution worked there as well +1.

Comment: and people wonder why the masses prefer OS X and windows...

Comment: On my laptop I did this, waited another 15 minutes and the button showed up

Comment: This can also happen with Elementary OS.

Comment: This just happened to me installing Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit using a USB stick created on a mac

Comment: How does this problem persist three years after the question was asked?

Comment: This just happend to me on a Acer Asipe 5250 from 2012. It stuck on installation type page. I restarted the proccess one more time. This time didn't connect to wifi and didn't select upgrade and third party programs. After that everything went well. This laptop has 2GB of RAM and AMD E300 CPU

Comment: I also experienced this installing 16.04. I believe it's tied to the "Download updates before install" option, as the previous screen (with this option selected) took some minutes to progress.

Comment: ElementryOs 2017 here.  Still the same problem. Still the same solution. Go figure... :-D

Comment: Yep, just happened to me with 16.04 LTS 32-bit. I had "download updates during install" on, but "install third-party blah blah" off. Pressed the Back button once, returned to the screen, and the "Install now" button was enabled.

Comment: I cant belive a software like ubuntu have this kind of bugs, a shame.

Comment: This still happens in 17.04. And back && continue still help. But WTF!

Comment: Did anybody open a bug report? Can we have the link to +1 there? Just happened to me installing Linux Mint 18.2 Mate 32bits, with "download update" and 3rd party checked. First time I see this problem (and I do a lot of installations) but the computer has a 2Ghz monocore proc and 2GB of RAM so yeah I guess that's what we call a lag.

Comment: Nothing worked for me.... infinite amounts of back and continue. I'm quitting this Ubuntu shit. It's a piece of shit system which also destroyed my data at work during dual boot _|_

Comment: Still happens with `17.10` too.

Comment: I can't believe it. This actually worked!!! I love ubuntu but a solution like this is something ridiculous. Just worked for me while downgrading from 16.10 to 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 11):

On Lubuntu 16.10, for me, not selecting "Download updates before install" solved the problem.

Comment: This worked for me when I had the same issue installing Mate 16.04.01

Comment: This worked also for me installing ubuntu 17.04 Beta 2

Comment: Worked.  The other option is checked.

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem installing Kubuntu 16.10 in VirtualBox. Unlike shao.lo, for me dynamic vs. fixed .vdi didn't matter. For me the problem was that the virtual disk was too small, but the installer doesn't give any useful error report about this. There is an icon on the screen indicating the issue, but it's so abstracted as to be meaningless: it looks like a trashcan with a line through it, with no accompanying explanation. (If the disk is adequate it will be a checkbox.) I created a new VDI of appropriate size (>8.6GB, apparently) and it worked.

I was only able to discover this by running "ubiquity -d" from a terminal and examining the output in /var/log/installer/debug.

Comment: This is exactly the issue. I will report it as a bug on launchpad. This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem trying to install Kubuntu 16.10 in VirtualBox.  Initially I had chosen a dynamic vdi disk.  The install would get to the second page of the install where "Install Updates as part of install" is.  No matter what I did the Continue button would always be greyed out.

I exited the vm and went back to settings to change the dynamic vdi to a fixed sized one.  That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem during install kubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. The problem was the size of the dynamic vdi disk. 
The default size of 8 GByte was not enough. After setting it to 256 GByte the installation was possible.

Answer (score 1):

Using Lubuntu 16.04.3, I ran into a similar problem (<kbd>Continue</kbd> button also grayed out). In my case I was able to "enable" that button, performing the steps below, for which [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/844406/387157) inspired me, and which includes:

> ... not selecting "Download updates before install" solved the problem

Steps to *enable* the <kbd>Continue</kbd> button ***anyway*** (starting from the screen where you're stuck with that button being disabled):

1. Use the <kbd>Back</kbd> button to return to the previous screen where you can select "Download updates before install" (I had this option also selected at first).
2. Continue again (to return to the screen where you got stuck), and at this point the <kbd>Continue</kbd> button is no longer disabled. However, as per the previous step the "Download updates before install" option is not selected either anymore, which is not really what I wanted ...
3. Do not actually hit the <kbd>Continue</kbd> button ...yet. Instead, use the <kbd>Back</kbd> button *again* to return to the previous screen where you can select "Download updates before install". Just enable (check) the "Download updates before install" option again, and continue again.
4. ***Eureca*** ... the <kbd>Continue</kbd> button is no longer disabled ... ***AND***  the "Download updates before install" option is selected *also*!
5. Now is the time to actually hit the <kbd>Continue</kbd> button ...

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, trying to install lubuntu 17.04 in my old Aspire One and that problem happen every time. Reading about the problem i found a question about the ACPI, so a decide to turn it off, but Lubuntu doents have the menu options to choose the grub parameters, then to change the boot options of the lubuntu you have to edit the file \boot\grub\loopback.cfg on the pendrive, and add the parameter "acpi=off", near the "boot=casper" i think its a good place.

this is my entry that works

```
menuentry "Install Lubuntu" {   
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed cdrom-detect/try-usb=true noprompt floppy.allowed_drive_mask=0 acpi=off ignore_uuid boot=casper only-ubiquity iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz 
}
```

and with that option the installer can go on