# Ubuntu 14.04 - Install Now button disabled

Tags: system-installation, button

Unable to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows XP because the "Install Now" button (and the Back button) are disabled on the Partitioning screen.

Any suggestions on how to proceed are appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an `ext*` partition with a mount point (for example `/`)?

Comment: This question may be of some interest: http://askubuntu.com/questions/295059/continue-button-grayed-out-in-installation-type-screen-during-13-04-installa