# "Back" and "Install Now" buttons grayed out in 14.04 installer

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

The "Back" and "Install Now" buttons are grayed out in the 14.04 installer. How do I restore them?

Comment: Where ? During a live-session installation of Ubuntu ?

Comment: Could you expand on live-session?

Comment: I booted from cd created from iso downloaded from Ubuntu site.

Comment: Okay, that's a live-session (not Ubuntu installed on your hard drive). Thanks

Comment: This is more than a "bug report." This is someone trying to move forward with an installation, despite the bug. No one who comes here cares that the bug be fixed if they're able to move on. I think bug workarounds are totally valid.

Comment: @brentonstrine Agree that this is more than a bug report. Really, what's the point with having this whole Ubuntu forum, if people are unable to install Ubuntu in the first place  :- /  I encountered the same problem today when installing Linux Mint. Glad I found this question & answer.

Answer (score 8):

This happens with both, DVD and USB. The issue appears when selecting the keyboard layout, before selecting partition or drive to use or in between. Simply put, the **Back**, **Install** or **Continue** buttons stop working. they are not selectable. The only good thing here is that you do not get both, **Back** and one of the other buttons grayed out at the same time. So you can go back and forth until the button appears to be clickable.

This is actually a bug so I will close as such. I suspect the fix will appear on 14.04.1

There is a bug report about it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1303945

And another similar question regarding 14.04 in [Ubuntu 14.04 - Install Now button disabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455463/ubuntu-14-04-install-now-button-disabled)

Comment: For me, both were greyed out simultaneously. It was on the timezone screen. I finally got it to work by deleting and re-typing the timezone. Eventually the dropdown allowed me to select a different timezone and when I did the "Continue" button became available.

Comment: so how the heck are you supposed to install the OS without the buttonss?

Comment: @Yuck Like i said, you would go back, then forward again. The continue will be working. Depending on where in the install steps, you would need to do stuff like brenton mentioned above.

Comment: yeah, go back, then the install now button is enabled again.

Comment: Still happening with 16

Comment: ok how to go back if back button is disabled is also greyed, I am sitting in front of my machine with this bug right now

Comment: ok solved by restart computer

Comment: with lubuntu 17.04 in my old Aspire One that problem happen too. In my case is a problem about the ACPI, so a decide to turn it off, but Lubuntu doesn't have the menu options to choose the grub parameters, then to change the boot options of the lubuntu you have to edit the file \boot\grub\loopback.cfg on the pendrive, and add the parameter "acpi=off", near the "boot=casper" i think its a good place