# Ubuntu stuck/freeze on install

Tags: system-installation

I've been trying to replace my current Windows 10 installation with Ubuntu 16.04. My computer is a Lenovo Thinkpad T470. I've formatted my 15GB USB-dongle. Downloaded the software Rufus, and burned the ISO onto the USB. I've tried the settings "MBR Partition for BIOS or UEFI", "MBR Partition for UEFI" and "GPT partition for UEFI". I've tried using memtest86+ to test if I have any memory errors, I have not. I've tried disabling Secure boot, and Fast startup. I've tried using other software than Rufus, and I've tried entering the "nomodeset" in the boot options, as well "acpi=off", nothing works.

When I boot from my USB. I choose "Install Ubuntu" from the grub menu. And then select my language in the installer. It is from this point on, it gets problematic. Sometimes when I try to connect to my WIFI, it connects successfully, but when I press the "continue" button, the installer freezes and nothing happens. Sometimes I get past this point, but it then freezes later on in the installation progress - typically right when I press the "Install now" button.

It should also be mentioned that, if I press the "Quit" button in the install. I get to a black screen with a lot of text saying something like squashfs error.

Can someone please help me? When I tried booting memtest86+ it only worked when I changed my boot mode from UEFI to Legacy. Could this be it? Are there any downsides to installing an operating system in legacy?

If anyone has any other suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I just used a different USB-thumb drive, and that did the trick.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If the Ubuntu installer either does not start or starts and then freezes, press the <kbd>F6</kbd> key and enable the `nomodeset` kernel boot option.

**Safe Graphics Mode**. A new option is added to the GRUB menu in 19.04 and later which will boot with nomodeset on. This may help you resolve issues on certain graphics cards and allow you to boot and install any proprietary drivers needed by your system.

From the purple ubuntu screen press the <kbd>F6</kbd> key. If you don't see this screen, shutdown, boot from the Ubuntu live USB again, and immediately after the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up a GNU GRUB menu screen. With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the GNU GRUB menu screen. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the GNU GRUB menu screen, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> is unnecessary.

[image]

After pressing F6, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on nomodeset and an "x" will appear to the left of the option. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave the popup menu. The selections are retained at the time the user presses the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. Then use the down arrow key to highlight the **Install Ubuntu** option and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to select it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Legacy boot didn't work either.

New info from user:  Legacy install option is grayed out.

According to users you can try:

1. Post by Umar: not selecting "Download updates before install" solved the problem.
2. Post by Steve Byrnes: I clicked "Back" and then "Continue" again, and now it works. Go figure...

[Update based on comments: If this doesn't work, try it again and/or wait 15 minutes.]

3. Maybe your installation iso image is somehow broken. I suggest changing flash disk, downloading ISO again and start the whole installation as never done before.

sources: ["Back" and "Install Now" buttons grayed out in 14.04 installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471642/back-and-install-now-buttons-grayed-out-in-14-04-installer)

["Continue button" grayed out in "installation type" screen during 13.04 installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295059/continue-button-grayed-out-in-installation-type-screen-during-13-04-installa)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1496229

Comment: I just tried to install Ubuntu in legacy mode. However the same thing happened. When I chose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu", and clicked "Install now", nothing happened, and the button got grayed out.

Comment: Thanks for further information, see edited answer please.